# nodeJS app, running node and webpack --watch?

Tags: node.js, webpack

brothers and sisters, I am trying to do this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/.bin/http-server ./public",
    "poststart": "webpack --watch"
  }
```

It is not working. The idea being `node` runs the app (duh) and there's a `webpack --watch` instance rebuilding my code as it changes. What's the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this:

- you start webpack --watch in one terminal to watch the sources and rebuild when changes occur
- you use nodemon (which is a npm package) in another terminal to watch for build (NOT source) changes and restart the app

Reference: https://nodemon.io/